# .htaccess rewrite with ? in url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

For SEO reasons I need to redirect an old URL: /index.php?paginaid=1 to www.example.com/

But when I try it like this below it becomes www.example.com/paginaid=1

Doesn't work:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php?paginaid=1$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Doesn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^paginaid=1$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.example.com? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

Any idea how to fix this?

My total .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php\?paginaid=1$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]

#RewriteRule ^index.php?paginaid=1$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^index.php?paginaid=2$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^index.php?paginaid=3$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^index.php?paginaid=4$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^index.php?paginaid=5$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^index.php?paginaid=6$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^index.php?paginaid=7$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^index.php?paginaid=8$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^index.php?paginaid=9$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^index.php?paginaid=10$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^index.php?paginaid=12$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^index.php?paginaid=13$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^index.php?page=archief$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^argeweb/weblog/2007/18/oebele.php$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^index.php?page=archief&aid=2006_9$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^index.php?page=archief&aid=2007_1$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^index.php?page=archief&aid=2008_10$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^index.php?page=categorie&cid=1$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^index.php?page=archief&aid=2007_5$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^argeweb/weblog/index.php?page=archief$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^argeweb/weblog/index.php?page=links$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]


AddDefaultCharset utf-8

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*internal\ dummy\ connection.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]

RewriteRule ^(manager|assets)/.*$ - [L]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico)$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=permanent,L] .
```

Comment: Your rule below **Doesn't work** is fine. Just place it at the top of your .htaccess

Comment: confirmed what @anubhava said. The second one works fine for me on a local box. Can you put your complete .htaccess _with_ the rewrite rule and a few lines from apache's error.log?

Comment: Both lines I seperately tried on top of my total htaccess. Can't find my log. tried with phpmyadmin binary log but can't look into it. Cleared cache, used different browsers.

Comment: I found this on FTP in the logs folder: 80.101.162.xxx - - [11/Feb/2015:09:28:15 +0100] "GET /?paginaid=1 HTTP/1.1" 301 309 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0"

Comment: `/index.php?paginaid=1` cannot become `/index.php/paginaid=1` with the rules shown. You have some other rules/code not shown here.

Comment: I have updated my total .htaccess. No idea whats going on, I'm going to try on an other website if it works there... didn't try that yet

Comment: Tried on a other site but there nothing happened. maybe this rule gives problems? : RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query string is not part of the match, so you'll need to include a rewrite condition based on `%{QUERY_STRING}`.

Also, .htaccess seems to append the original query string if nothing is added to the rewrite location, so to solve that, you add a lone `?`.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^paginaid=1$
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://www.example.com/? [R=301,L]
```

Also, your global `index.php` rule is overriding the `paginaid` rule, so move it above. Here is your full .htaccess that is working with the `paginaid` rule:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^paginaid=1$
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://www.example.com? [R=302,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^paginaid=2$
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://www.example.com? [R=302,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^paginaid=3$
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://www.example.com/? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*internal\ dummy\ connection.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]

RewriteRule ^(manager|assets)/.*$ - [L]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico)$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=permanent,L] .
```

Comment: Hey thanks!, it does work but all other URLs get http://www.example.com/?q=about so the ?q= is being added.

Comment: That's because of the second rule. Are you trying to handle all query strings for index.php? How do you need it to work?

Comment: (modx evolution) I need to handle all pages like normal -> /about etc. There are some old URLs which are indexed by google and need to redirect them to the homepage. So all is left now would be is removing ?q= I guess.

Comment: The first rule set checks query string and redirects based on that. You could copy that set for the URLs you need to redirect. Remove that second one, as it's acting as a catch-all (because it doesn't have the query string condition).

Comment: Hey thanks Bitwise, its working now! Indeed needed to remove 
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L] I have updated your example.